# How can I use a listview and still use an actionbar?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I'm writing a MainActivity that extends AppCompatActivity. In the oncreate method I instantiate a ListView object with the getListView() method, but that method is not recognized.

It is as if my MainActivity would have to extend ListActivity but then I lose the action bar. Is there a quick and easy way to use a ListView in a MainActivity that has an action bar?

Answer (score 3):

AppCompatActivity is not ListViewActivity, so You don't have getListView() method. To use list view You must add it in xml layout file and use findViewById() to use in activity.

Comment: Use a fragment in main activity

Answer (score 1):

Can you use

```
Listview list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
```